# How to redirect using css?

Tags: css, redirect

How I can redirect to another webpage using `CSS`?
anyway to do that is acceptable. I can **only** edit style nothing more.

Comment: You can't. CSS is for styling/animating purposes only

Comment: Redirect using CSS? NO

Comment: CSS = Cascading Style Sheet and it does what it means. Styling. No redirecting.

Comment: @Misha Zaslavsky: Wow, almost a word for word duplicate at that.

Comment: this question have no answer.so I should delete it?

Comment: @mpower: With pure CSS it is not possible. If you give more context, maybe there are other alternate solutions/approaches we can suggest. Btw, I don't think you can delete a question which has answers provided

Comment: so that's impossible.thanks all.

Comment: Funny Question. If you know the site has an imagelink, you can take the image, pull it overthe whole site, change the image to show a text like "click here for redirct" and change the href to your site.

Comment: I said I can't edit anything expect style.

Comment: thats an only style solution. you just cant force a click with css, but you can limit the user to only option of clicking your link (or back, or close the browser, you know..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't**

CSS is a styling language designed to give styles & animations to the elements in HTML

You'll need to use Javascript, and we'd be able to help more if you updated your question with some more information :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant, CSS is only used to style the page.

But check out this Jquery redirect which you should be able to add [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)